# On a theorem of Burnside

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

The following is a well known theorem of Burnside, which I am reading from the original paper.

*If $G$ is a finite $p$-group and $\{S_1,S_2,\cdots, S_n\}$ is a set of elements of $G$ such that their images in $G/[G,G]$ is a (minimal) generating set for $G/[G,G]$ then $\{ S_1,S_2,\cdots, S_n\}$ is a minimal generating set for $G$* .

I know a proof of this theorem which uses some characterization of the Frattini subgroup of a $p$-group. But, **I will be happy if one can explain the original proof of Burnside (see [link](http://plms.oxfordjournals.org/content/s2-13/1/6.extract))**. I came at this proof by a comment of Philip Hall, who himself couldn't clarify the proof of Burnside.

Comment: I agree with you that the original proof is not easy to be understanded. Although this can be proved easily in another way.

Comment: Unfortunately, the paper doesn't appear to be freely accessible on the web. Do you know of any place where it can be read without cost?

Comment: I haven't looked at it yet, but if Philip Hall could not clarify it, then I don't suppose I can!

Comment: I think the proof is just the usual idea that the derived subgroup consists of non-generators. One step is left unclear, but follows from the usual proof. Let $H$ denote any proper overgroup of $X=\langle S_1,\ldots,S_n \rangle$ and let $K$ be any normal supplement of $X$ in $H$, then the hypotheses all work in $G=H/(K \cap X)$ so we can assume $G=X \ltimes K$ (with Burnside calling this K by the name L). Take $L$ to be index $p$ in $G$ to miss a specific generator of $K$ (this step probably uses the Frattini subgroup), and then we get that $G' \leq L$, so it cannot miss the generator.

Comment: @jpvee: I agree with you. I don't think that it is free anywhere. Unfortunately, the proof can by "partly" seen on the link http://books.google.co.in/books?id=qAj_sgkzjvAC&pg=PA1340&lpg=PA1340&dq=collected+works+of+william+burnside&source=bl&ots=E87GdXVJsT&sig=LYmuhAneGuGf3beZUMf16HwzYAA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=ssX1UujLMMTnrAfCkoGgDw&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=collected%20works%20of%20william%20burnside&f=false. see page 1385.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This follows Jack's comment. I write in modern group theory symbols: First, consider the case that $G'$ is abelian.(I think this is the key point).

Consider $\bar{G}=G/G'$. Let $\bar{s}_1, \cdots, \bar{s}_n$ be the minimal generating set of $\bar{G}$, where $s_i \in G$. Let $S=\langle s_1, \cdots s_n \rangle$. Then $G=SG'$. Let $N=S\cap G'$. Since $G'$ is abelian in this case, we get $N \unlhd G$. Now we can consider $\tilde{G}=G/N$. Now $\tilde{G}=\tilde{S}\ltimes \tilde{G}'$. Let $\tilde{K}$ be a subgroup of index $p$ in $\tilde{G}'$. We can even choose $\tilde{K}$ to be normal in $\tilde{G}$ for $G$ is a $p$-group. Let $\tilde{L}=\tilde{S} \tilde{L}$, then $\tilde{G}/\tilde{L}$ is order $p$, and $\tilde{G}' \le \tilde{L}$, contrary the choice of $\tilde{L}$.

Now the general case: As above we get $s_i$ and $S$. Suppose $G'' \ne 1$. Let $\bar{G}=G/G''$. Non $\bar{s}_i$ and $\bar{S}$ work by above. So we get $\bar{G}=\bar{S}$, i.e. $G=SG''$. In this way, we can get $G=SG^{(3)},\cdots$. But $G$ is $p$-group, and $G^{(m)}=1$ for some $m$. So we complete this proof.